# Unexpected character '$' jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have created a new web site in vs 2012, the site was created with some default pages (new feature in vs 2012). Now I have added a .js file into my solution. I have called this .js file on my .aspx page like :-

```
<script src="../../Scripts/Login/Login.js" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" runat="server"></script>
```

But when I open the page in browser it gives an error Unexpected character '$'.

Comment: Try switching $ to jQuery (e.g. $.ajax() to jQuery.ajax() ).

Comment: have you add jquery reference??

Comment: that's means your jQuery is not loaded. Please recheck your JQuery Reference or add:

Comment: I have already added jquery ref. using Nuget manager..

Comment: nuget manager doesn't import jquery in your page, just on the project

Answer (score 2):

Try this way, you missed jQuery library:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/Login/Login.js" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" runat="server"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to include jquery library before you load `Login.js` file.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/Login/Login.js" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" runat="server"></script>
```

Comment: @Sandy, have you put these two lines in your page's footer?

Comment: I have place the lines on TitleContent of Login.apsx page

Answer (score 0):

If the other answers don't help (meaning you did actually include jQuery) it might be in conflict with some other library that overwrites / deletes the `$` function.

In that case you can just use the long-hand version `jQuery` instead. `$` is just a shorthand synonym for `jQuery`.

Answer (score -1):

It may be a conflict with some other libraries.
You can try running jQuery in a 'noConflict' mode to change the '$' sign into something else:
[jQuery.noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

Comment: If `$` is an unexpected character, this cannot be a name collision.